# R- Data Analytic syntax

Tags: r, data-analysis

Purpose : I want to repeat the analysis i have already done in python using R.codes are below kindly help write equivalent code in R:

**Question no 1:**
For below table

```
caught            bowled           run out               lbw           stumped
62                21                 8                 4                 4
caught and bowled        hit wicket
2                 1
```

````
But then I when I converted it back to `dataframe` for using `ggplot` it so coming as

    A Freq
    1  1    1
    2  2    1
    3  4    2
    4  8    1
    5 21    1
    6 62    1

How to i avoid this? kindly advice?

******Question no 2 :****

```python code is as below: 
len(df_warner\[df_warner\['batsman_runs'\]==6\]) 

# what is Eqivalent R syntax?

df_six<-df_warner2[(df_warner2$batsman_runs==6),]

nrow(df_six)  # worked well
````

Comment: You could remove NAs : `df_warner[!is.na(df_warner$dismissal_kind)]`

Comment: will this work for blank values too?

Comment: this will only with NAs, `""` isn't NA

Comment: df_warner <- df_warner[!(df_warner$dismissal_kind == ""), ]  # i used this to to remove blanks value.worked out  thanks for your response.

Comment: To count no of  sixes  i used  below code: 

df_six<-df_warner2[(df_warner2$batsman_runs==6),]

length(df_six) 

Result : how ever it is not swing correct result instead show no of variables i.e 21

when i use  dim(df_six) command its is showing correctly but along side no of variable. 
Result : 160, 21 # Shall i use this mehtod alway or is there any more clear command for this purpose

Comment: try `nrow` instead of `length` . A dataframe is a list of columns, hence the result you got.

Comment: Thanks alot. worked well.  i even tried table using sort command :)

df_totalruns <-sort(table(df_warner2$batsman_runs), decreasing = TRUE)
head(df_totalruns)

  0    1    4    2    6    3 
1124  997  401  207  160   13